# NSInternalInconsistencyException after upgrade to iOS 6

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash

We receive a lot of crashlogs only from devices on iOS 6 with exception

```
Exception   : request for rect at invalid index path ( 2 indexes [0, 0]) (NSInternalInconsistencyException)

....
3   CoreFoundation                      0x34d5857f  + 614
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33068a65  + 128
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x31eb207b  + 78
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x31eb2114  + 19
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x31eb3599 __cxa_current_exception_type + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x330689d1 objc_exception_rethrow + 12
9   CoreFoundation                      0x34c9ef21 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
10  CoreFoundation                      0x34c9ed49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
11  GraphicsServices                    0x351db2eb GSEventRunModal + 74
12  UIKit                               0x3607d301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
```

Application don't calls method rectForRowAtIndexPath: explicitly.
Please help to find reason.

Comment: You could perhaps try to reproduce it on simulator ?

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce this behaviour, because crash happens deep in framework. Do you know which public method calls rectForRowAtIndexPath: (or other method which can raise this exception)?

Comment: I'd bet on something about UITableView, loading rows maybe.

Comment: It looks like the UITableView datasource method: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Why? It is possible to reproduce in this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception rises when you select (touch) row in the empty UIPickerView segment. It happens only under iOS 6.

Comment: this is happening even in iOS 6.1.3. any solution for that ?